# WebRTC and RTMP wowza

Tags: flash, rtmp, webrtc, wowza

I am working on a video conference web project which uses Wowza RTMP and Flex for the audio/video to work on desktop browsers. Now, I want to make it work on the tablet and phone browsers and noticed WebRTC is getting popular in portable devices. I also heard about openTok api which is charged based on minutes used, but i don't want to use such products since we want to control the media server like what we are doing with wowza server.

Our goal is to use WebRTC(just for audio and video) for protable devices which can communicate to our RTMP server in some way so that we can provide support to old browsers using flash and new browsers with WebRTC seemlessly. Is this something possible? If so how to integrate webRTC with wowza or any RTMP server ?

Comment: First of all, I wish you success in your work. Wowza and webrtc.www.boltora.com

Answer (score 1):

As you said, Wowza is an RTMP Server and its main feature is to process streams from Flash applications. But it can also translate Flash packets to RTP packets, that is a standard protocol for VoIP applications.

With WebRTC, browsers are able to send data from media devices using SRTP, but it has some extra protocols attached, like the use of BUNDLE, the session establishment using ICE(STUN/TURN), and the fact that the streams are encrypted with DTLS.

Wowza does not support all these specific protocols, but you can implement an application to extend Wowza and do it yourself using other available libraries that are supporting WebRTC.

Comment: You are right. It is possible to develop a Wowza server-side application which supports all WebRTC stack. However it's not a simple task because it covers a lot of work related WebRTC session establishment with DTLS, packetization, transcoding of H.264 RTMP stream into WebRTC compatible VP8, sending VP8 through WebRTC session, etc.

Answer (score 1):

RTMP is fundamentally incompatible with WebRTC, but you can set up teleconferencing with just WebRTC.

Wowza doesn't support WebRTC yet but did [indicate plans](https://www.wowza.com/products/capabilities/webrtc-streaming-software) to add support for it.

At the moment the only serious WebRTC Server is [Lynckia/Licode](http://lynckia.com/licode/) although they don't offer server-side recording yet so if you need that you're out of luck for now.

If you really want to integrate both RTMP and WebRTC based video conferencing you'd need to do a lot of custom development at the moment still.

Comment: It should be noted that since this answer was given, Wowza has begun supporting WebRTC (follow the newly edited `indicate plans` link in this answer to read about it)

Answer (score 0):

there are some other projects which has support for webrtc and is server based take a look at the following ones:

1. http://code.google.com/p/telepresence/
2. https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't strictly answer your question, but as nakib mentioned, Wowza can translate RTMP packets into RTP. So if you want a mobile app to communicate with Flash, the best way seems to base the mobile app on RTP. In fact, this is just the approach that OpenTok [adopted](http://www.tokbox.com/blog/opentok-ios-sdk-behind-the-scenes/) back in the day for version 1 of their API before they went all way WebRTC in OpenTok 2.0.

Given the above, I would still consider basing the mobile app on WebRTC but have a "legacy mode" in it that would use RTP specifically for the Flash-via-Wowza connections.

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is AddLive (http://www.addlive.com). We do support all the browsers and also mobile SDKs

Comment: I'm looking something open source.

Comment: AddLive has been acquired by SnapChat and is no longer a product.